# unable to make a fix-after-scrolling div with a fixed menubar at the top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with a fixed menubar at the top.

I also have a `div` which is below that menubar with another `div` at the middle.

I want that `div` (the third one) to be fixed below the menubar(the first one) after it reaches just below that menubar(the first `div`) after scrolling. I know this is very confusing so I've mentioned the JSFiddle link.

https://jsfiddle.net/acharyarupak391/3659kn2f/29/

```js
$(function() {
  // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
  var stickyTop = $('#sticky').offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).stickyTop() > stickyTop) {
      $('#sticky').css({ position: 'fixed', top: '100px' });
    } else {
      $('#sticky').css({ position: 'static', top: '100px' });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#menubar {
  background: red;
  width: 100%; height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.8;
  /* made this transparent so that it would be visible what is happening behind */
}

#unsticky {
  position: absolute;
  background: brown;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%; height: 100px;
}

#sticky {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 200px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%; height: 750px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menubar">
    This is the fixed menubar
  </div>

  <div id="unsticky">
    this is the unsticky/movable div
  </div>

  <div id="sticky">
    as this div reaches just below the menubar(first div) after scrolling, it is supposed to be fixed there
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just CSS by using [Sticky Positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example#Sticky_positioning)

The problem you may have though (wether you use a CSS or JS solution) is that if the `sticky` content is higher than the viewport you wont be able to scroll to the bottom of it once 'fixed' unless you give it a fixed height and `overflow:auto;`. So the most appropriate solution will depend specifically on your use case. Hopefully this will get you some of the way.

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#menubar {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.8;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  /* made this transparent so that it would be visible what is happening behind */
}

#unsticky {
  background: brown;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

#sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
  color: white;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menubar">
    This is the fixed menubar
  </div>

  <div id="unsticky">
    this is the unsticky/movable div
  </div>

  <div id="sticky">
    as this div reaches just below the menubar(first div) after scrolling, it is supposed to be fixed there
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Some more unsticky content Some more unsticky content</p>
    <p>Some more unsticky content Some more unsticky content</p>
    <p>Some more unsticky content Some more unsticky content</p>
    <p>Some more unsticky content Some more unsticky content</p>
    <p>Some more unsticky content Some more unsticky content</p>
    <p>Some more unsticky content Some more unsticky content</p>
    <p>Some more unsticky content Some more unsticky content</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

If a CSS-only solution doesn't float your boat you can do something similar with JavaScript, but there are still fundamental problems with your approach. All the absolute positioning complicates stuff and I'm not sure that its required, but the main problem is once the `#sticky` content is `fixed` how will you un-fix it again? How will the user get to content that's below it? Will there be any? What if they're on a tiny mobile? What if the height of your elements changes (maybe due to browser or font-size changes)? Your approach will depend on exactly what you are trying to achieve. I'm not sure that I understand quite what that is but here's your corrected JS. Perhaps between the two examples you can construct something that works well for your use-case.

```js
$(function() {
  //define the sticky element 
  var $sticky = $('#sticky'); //fetch once use many times
  //define the point at which sticky gets stuck
  var stickAt = $('#menubar').height();
  // Check the initial position of the Sticky Header
  var stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    //console.log(stickyTop, stickAt);

    if (stickyTop < stickAt) {
      $('#sticky').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '100px',
        marginTop: 0,
        height: '100%',
        overflow: 'auto'
      });
    } else {
    /* As soon as #sticky becomes fixed the scrollPosition will change and this gets triggers so you're kind of stuck in a loop. UNCOMMENT to see what I mean
      $('#sticky').css({
        position: 'static',
        marginTop: '200px'
      });
      */
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#menubar {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  /*added top*/
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.8;
  /* made this transparent so that it would be visible what is happening behind */
}

#unsticky {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: brown;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

#sticky {
  position: static;
  margin-top: 200px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 750px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="menubar">
    This is the fixed menubar
  </div>

  <div id="unsticky">
    this is the unsticky/movable div
  </div>

  <div id="sticky">
    as this div reaches just below the menubar(first div) after scrolling, it is supposed to be fixed there
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>q</p>
  </div>
</body>
```